# Cost and Usage Report : Rules when a period is closed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk, cloud

We are using the csv files generated as part of the Cost and Usage Report in order to bill our customers.
Looking at documentation provided (link below) I have a few questions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-reports-costusage.html

*The reports that AWS generates throughout the month are estimated and are subject to change during the rest of the month, as you incur more usage.*

 - It seems that records created in one file can be updated in the next. 

 - **Question 1** When can we be sure then the records will no longer be updated? is it when bill/InvoiceId filed has ID in it?

 - **Question 2** Is there any property in the file that indicates that the records has been changed from what previously was sent? example ModifiedDate?

*AWS finalizes the report at the end of each month. Finalized reports have the calculations for your blended and unblended costs, and cover all of your usage for the month. AWS might update reports after they have been finalized if AWS applies refunds, credits, or support fees to your usage for the month after finalizing your bill.*

 - **Question 3** : Is there any type of indication that a csv file is a FINAL for the period, and after that no more changes will be done?

- **Question 4** : Are the records in the csv file order by Date of Creation?
i.e. Is there any straightforward way to see what has been added to the file compared to the file we received in the previous day?

Thank you!

Comment: This isn't a programming question and falls outside the scope of this website. Serverfault *might* be a more appropriate site to post this, but that's questionable. This is really a question for AWS support.

Comment: I agree, but when i search stackoverflow there are many similar questions related to aws billing and cost and usage report. So I though maybe someone has the answers!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a billing question for AWS support.

Comment: 1. You can't. 2. No, 3. No, 4. No. I saw sometimes the report is updated 2 months later. There are no indications for the modified, final, fixed records.

Comment: But the invoice will be filled when the month ends.